# how to create invalid utf-8 characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to test some application level ruby methods and how they handle invalid utf-8. I'm trying something like to get invalid utf-8:

```
mysql> update items set header=UNHEX('4D2AFF') where id=10938;
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xFF' for column 'header' at row 1
```

Is there a way to update a varchar(255) to invalid utf-8?

Comment: Wikipedia documents some invalid UTF-8 values.  Perhaps you can just give it a try. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not changing the text strings to a `binary` encoding or non-utf8 encoding, or to use binary strings (varbinary, blobs)? That will allow you to store all invalid values that you want.

**Edit:** To be more specific: change the type to `varchar(255) charset binary`, that may cause you all kind of charset problems .

@RLF, funny that you mention Wikipedia, text on the wikipedia is stored in binary format!